# wicket dropdown choice getting reset to "choose one" on validation error

Tags: wicket

I have a dropdown list with few rows in a table. All the dropdown are required fields. if none of the dropdown list has been selected and a user select only one dropdown and tries to save. A validation error is thrown which is correct,  the problem is the value for the selected dropdown choice gets reset to "Choose one". how can i correct that?

Comment: I just want to make sure You mean when the validation fails page/Dropdown reset ?

Comment: What Model does the DropDown use (Datatype) and do you use a ChoiceRenderer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wicket uses the `IChoiceRenderer#getIdValue()` to find the selected option. If you do not provide custom `IChoiceRenderer` then Wicket will use `ChoiceRenderer` and as an `id` it will use the index of the item in the `List` of options.

See the usages of #equals() at https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/7bef3d67c8ccc269f02e8943bf9a22c3cd5438e9/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/AbstractSingleSelectChoice.java. Even better fire the debugger and see what happens!

Comment: That doesn't seem right to me. In the class you posted The equals method is only used on the ID value from the ChoiceRenderer which is a String. And String equal implementation isn't something you can change or should worry about. I would rather guess that his ChoiceRenderer doesn't correctly implement the methods `getIdValue` and/or `getObject`